# Как завершить ShellExecute?

Tags: c++, winapi

Так понимаю, что если `ShellExecuteW` возвращает `Hinstance`, то значит есть способ закрыть поток. Как мне это сделать? И есть ли возможность поставить это на паузу?

Comment: ShellExecuteW возвращает просто целое число, который имеет тип Hinstance для обратной совместимости. И к потокам она не имеет отношения... Что тут имеется ввиду под "поставить на паузу" непонятно. Если хотите запустить еще один процесс, а потом приостановить все его потоки, то используйте CreateProcess + thread helper API (CreateToolhelp32Snapshot и тд).

Comment: @user7860670 а вот `ShellExecuteW` возвращает число. его можно как то закрыть или завершить? проблема такая. в списке может быть несколько каталогов. и все они архивируются в одно время. но иногда архивирование не нужно делать и тогда нужно как то отменить это. можно конечно убить процесс, но простому пользователю это неудобно.

Comment: ShellExecuteW сам по себе ничего такого не предлагает, а возвращаемое значение служит только для проверки успешности вызова. Если winrar не предоставляет средств для внезапного прерывания, то тогда только убивать процесс.